# MySql Order By - Custom sort by value and name

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

I have the following table structure:

```
CLIENT | YEAR | TOTAL_EARNED
```

With sample data:

```
John  | 2016 | 100
Jane  | 2016 | 50
Joe   | 2016 | 300
John  | 2017 | 200
Jane  | 2017 | 50
Joe   | 2017 | 0
```

I want to get it sorted by TOTAL_EARNED but also want to keep the client records together:

```
Joe   | 2016 | 300
Joe   | 2017 | 0
John  | 2017 | 200
John  | 2016 | 100
Jane  | 2016 | 50
Jane  | 2017 | 50
```

Any way to do that?

Comment: So.... if Joe earned 300 in 2017 and 100 in 2016, but John earned 400 in 2016 and 50 in 2017; who should be listed first?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using a subquery in `order by`:

```
select t.*
from t
order by (select max(t2.total_earned) from t t2 where t2.client = t.client) desc,
         client,
         year
```

There are other approaches (such as using a `join`), but this one is "fun".

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with the JOIN version Gordon alluded to; something like this should guarantee the exact results you provided as example.

```
SELECT t0.*
FROM t AS t0
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT t.CLIENT, MAX(t.TOTAL_EARNED) AS bestEarned 
    FROM t 
    GROUP BY t.CLIENT
 ) AS tBest ON t0.CLIENT= tBest.CLIENT
ORDER BY tBest.bestEarned DESC
       , t0.CLIENT ASC
       , t0.TOTAL_EARNED DESC
       , t0.YEAR
;
```